# Steenrod algebra: Ádem relations from Milnor product formula

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, steenrod-algebra

The question is how to deduce the Ádem relations from the Milnor product formula. Straightforward approach leads to certain relation on binomial coefficients mod p. 
Could anyone tell me if there is a reference to any kind of answer?

Answer (score 4):

This has been shown by Daniel Cohen:

**[On the Adem relations](https://doi.org/10.1017/s0305004100035179).** 
Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 57 1961 265–267.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I thought about